# Nato code string return value for input string javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I have string where I need to convert the entered string into NATO code equivalent.

Such as input string **abc** and get **alpha beta charlie**

So far I have done this code, I would like to compare once I have the each character, any suggestions

```
let str = 'abc';
let res = '';

const codes = [
      {
        'a': 'alpha'
      },
      {
        'b': 'beta'
      },
      {
        'c': 'charlie'
      }
    ];

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
     codes.find((item, index) => {
      if (str[i] === item) {
         console.log('found item', item[i]);
         res = res + item; 
     }
     });
}

console.log(res);
```

any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Use an object instead of an array of objects.

Comment: `Such as input string abc and get ** alpha beta charlie **` with the suggestion from jabaa this would be a nice case for a oneliner split->map->join

Comment: I tried using object as well, and was trying to get all the keys of the object @jabba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use even your array of objects. but you need add more logic to find the code value inside of an array of objects.

```js
let str = 'abc';
let res = '';

const codes = [
      {
        'a': 'alpha'
      },
      {
        'b': 'beta'
      },
      {
        'c': 'charlie'
      }
    ];
function getCode(codes, char){
    return Object.values(codes.find(e=>Object.keys(e).indexOf(char)!=-1))[0];
}
res = getCode(codes, str[0]);
for (let i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
    res = res + " " + getCode(codes, str[i]);
}

console.log(res); //alpha beta charlie
```

Comment: Thank you for another approach I had tried single method and had used Object.keys method to pull all keys as well. But your solution I can learn more now. Its a good Learning for me as well now @Steverst1

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object called `codes` containing all the alphabet chars and theirs equivalent nato strings together with a `convert` function like below:

```js
const codes = {'a': 'alpha', 'b': 'beta', 'c': 'charlie'};

function convert(str) {
    return str.split('').map(code => codes[code]).join(' ');
}

console.log(convert('a'));   //it will print alpha
console.log(convert('ab'));  //it will print alpha beta
console.log(convert('abc')); //it will print alpha beta charlie
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the above code. I believe the codes array of object which I made is not the way working out in my loops.Thanks a lot for your contribution here.